# Kudos Vs. bravo

Tags: word-usage

Has the word **kudos** outdated the word or exclamation **bravo!**

Here's what Google Ngram shows:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kudos&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckudos%3B%2Cc0

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bravo&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbravo%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Bravo! for the downvote!

Comment: Minus 2 pts in the StackExchange -I'm going to lose sleep for this!

Answer (score 5):

It never occurred to me to use these words in the same way. (Although some do.) One would "give kudos" (like offering congratulations) on/for a job well done.  *Bravo, or *brava*, is almost always used to laud a performance of some kind. (Including falling down an entire flight of stairs and landing on one's feet, or even having a baby.)

"Kudos," is more of an affirmation, while "Bravo!"/"Brava!" is always an exclamation.